# Can't submit form with UserCreationForm

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm learning django with v1.8 and I'm trying to create a form, but submit doesn't work and I don't have error..
If someone can help me, it will be very nice. Thank you

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render

def register(request):
if request.method == "POST" :
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/account')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'polls/register.html', args)
```

**register.htlm**

```
   {% block content %}
        <form action="polls/register.html" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="button">button</button>
        </form>  
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why **Django 1.8** while **Django 2.x** out there?

Comment: It's for a training, I can only use this version

Comment: If you don’t have an error, so most probably the request isn’t reaching the backend at all. Would you please provide your url router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `button type` tag to `input`

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```